# Plotting logistic regression line

Tags: arrays, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression, logistic-regression

this is my first post ever here so I'm not quit sure what is the proper form to ask the question. I'm trying to put picture of the results but since its my first post, the website telling me that I need 10 positive post for some credibility so I think that my charts doesn't appear. Also, I'm french, not perfectly bilingual. Please, be indulgent, I'm open for all comments and suggestions. I really need this for my master's projet. Thank you very much!

I have two sets of arrays which contains thousands of values In one (x_1_3) is all the value of temperature and y_0_100 contain only 0's and 100's which are associated to every temperature in x_1_3 sorted.

```
    x_1_3 = array([[ 2.02],
   [ 2.01],
   [ 3.08],
   ...,
   [ 0.16],
   [ 0.17],
   [-2.12]])

y_0_100 = array([  0.,   0.,   0., ..., 100., 100., 100.])
```

The 0 in y_0_100 represent solid precipitation and 100 represent liquid precipitation I just want to plot a logistic regression line across my values

(I also tried to put the values in a dataframe, but it didnt work)

```
     dfsnow_rain
AirTemp liquid%
0   2.02    0.0
1   2.01    0.0
2   3.08    0.0
3   3.05    0.0
4   4.89    0.0
... ... ...
7526    0.78    100.0
7527    0.40    100.0
7528    0.16    100.0
7529    0.17    100.0
7530    -2.12   100.0
7531 rows × 2 columns



X = x_1_3
y = y_0_100
# Fit the classifier
clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)
clf.fit(X, y)

# and plot the result
plt.figure(1, figsize=(10, 5))
plt.clf()
plt.scatter(X.ravel(), y, color='black', zorder=20)
X_test = np.linspace(-15, 15, 300)

loss = expit(X_test * clf.coef_ + clf.intercept_).ravel()
plt.plot(X_test, loss, color='red', linewidth=3)

ols = linear_model.LinearRegression()
ols.fit(X, y)
plt.plot(X_test, ols.coef_ * X_test + ols.intercept_, linewidth=1)
#plt.axhline(1, color='.5')

plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.xticks(range(-10, 10))
plt.yticks([0, 100, 10])
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.legend(('Logistic Regression Model', 'Linear Regression Model'),
           loc="lower right", fontsize='small')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Chart results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJ4sg.png)

When I zoom in I realise that my logistic regression line is not flat, its the line that curves in a very small range (see picture below)

[Chart when it's zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZJ5w.png)

I would like something more like this :

[Logistic regression chart i would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6pEo.png)

What am i doing wrong here? I just want to plot a regression line across my values from y0 to y100

Comment: Maybe you could assign `y = y_0_100 / 100` at the start? That way both your `y` and your logistics function have 0 and 1 as values. Now your y has 0 and 100.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed hahah it works perfectly well ! Thank you so so much! I really appreciate it!